What does this NMOS/PMOS connected to Vout do in this TIA (Trans-impedance amplifier)?
I was trying to understand a TIA (Trans-impedance Amplifier) design by Behzad Razavi which I found here.
But I don't get what the transistor marked below, which is connected to the Vout, does?
I even tried removing it from the circuit in spice simulations and it didn't affect the output (at least in terms of the trans impedance gain)

(Source: "The Design of a Transimpedance Amplifier" by Behzad Razavi in The Analog Mind from IEEE Solid-State Circuits Magazine, Winter 2023, pp 7 - 11, DOI: 10.1109/MSSC.2022.3219682)
I am trying to design my own discrete TIA by using his design as a reference, I have replaced RD2 with a 1 Mega-Ohm resistor since I want a transimpedance gain of 10^6 i.e. a 1mV output for a 1nA input current. I have used a CD4007 transistor array for my PMOS-es and a 2N7000 transistor for M1. Also, I read somewhere that the transistor is supposed to be a PMOS, so I am using a transistor from the array for instead of an NMOS.

This transistor is there only to model the input device of the next stage.


I don't get what the transistor marked below, which is connected to the Vout, does?

TIA design isn't my forté but the answer (as commented by G36) is stated within the article, on page 5 of that PDF:


The Complete Design
{...}
The circuit also includes a 5 μm / 30 nm transistor as the output load to model the input device of the next stage.


